# Android Vitamio 5.0.1 can not upload to google play

Tags: android, vitamio

I use the library vitamio for streaming in android. When I upload to google play, an alert shows "Your APK has been rejected for containing security vulnerabilities, which violates the Malicious Behavior policy. If you submitted an update, the previous version of your app is still live on Google Play."

How to fix this ?

Comment: File a bug report for the library. This is not the right place to post this.

Comment: Usually you'll get this message from Google when your apk contains `TrustAllCerts` code. Either you are using these kind of classes or your library is. Verify before you submit

Answer (score 0):

In vitamio libs folder please remove arm64 folder then you can upload to google play.

Comment: Thanks for replying! I've already deleted arm64 bit and uploaded to Google Play Store. So my application cannot be run on x64 processors